# Populate Silverlight fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser

I've done some searching for an answer to this and couldn't locate anything, so if this is a duplicate post feel free to hound me and point me to the existing one :)

I'm using a Silverlight web application which doesn't have an import feature for user information.  I don't have access to this source code so I can't modify it.  So right now I'm forced to enter it all by hand (copy/paste each field).  I have all of the user data electronically stored in another database.

What I'm looking to do is be able to open up a page for user information (name, address, height, etc) and be able to use a javascript in the browser to auto-populate these with information from the database.  I'm pretty good with Javascript so let's put that aside.

The main question here: Is there a way to get the names of fields of a Silverlight application running in the browser to be able to do anything like this?  Looking at the page source I don't see any field names.  Just some script references to the actual Silverlight app and some initParams (not sure if these can be modified by js but my guess is it's too late by the time the page has loaded).

Appreciate any help you can provide.  This is my first encounter with Silverlight from a coding perspective.

Thanks,

Kris

Comment: Did this work https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/15347a79-438d-459e-9c01-c04943221aa2/how-to-access-silverlight-objects-from-javascript-function-?forum=silverlightjavascript

Comment: You can pass information in the initParams to the silverlight application, but you have to modify the application to use that information to pre-populate any fields (as you have to with prems89 suggestion). Is that application under your control at all? If not, I don't think there's anything you can do.